# "Case folding" error trying to clone a mercurial repo

Tags: mercurial

I try to clone a local mercurial repository on windows.

I get this error:

```
   C:\temp\toolkit1.1>hg clone \src\toolkit
   destination directory: toolkit
   updating working directory
   abort: case-folding collision between sdk/Api.h and sdk/api.h
```

It looks like I changed capitalization of API.H at some point, but I don't know how to resolve this. Any tips?

I am using the version: 1.2.1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a problem that sometimes occurs when you work with a Mercurial repository on a case-insensitive file system (Windows). See the [Fixing Case Collisions](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/FixingCaseCollisions) on the Mercurial wiki.

Probably the easiest is if you have access to a Unix computer check out the project there and remove the offending file, merging changes first (if any), then commit and push.

Comment: For sake of completeness: case-folding-collisions can occur on linux/unix systems if a file in repo gets renamed from e.g. Api.h to api.h. Everyone screams at Windows, but it happened to me on Mac, without Windows anywhere near.

Comment: That's because mac, as well as windows, despite being a unix system it still is case-insensitive.............

Comment: Just in case someone makes a wrongful assumption from @Cek's comment: a change in case in the opposite direction, i.e. api to Api, will cause problems too

Comment: To add to the list of possible causes, this happened to me on pure Linux when trying to clone to a pen drive formatted as FAT32.

Comment: @Flatline: there's a very distinct difference as to whether the software/runtime is case-sensitive or not. Your statement as it stands is wrong. NTFS *is* case-sensitive. The Win32 *subsystem* is case-insensitive. On the other hand in Win32 a file cannot have a trailing `.` in its name, whereas on NTFS as such this isn't a problem and another subsystem such as SFU can handle those fine (also file names with different case but in the same folder).

Comment: Are there any other workarounds if you don't have a unix machine available?

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by renaming the file in windows to Api.h.old. Committing that. Then renaming to Api.h with corrected capitalization. Commiting again.

Then clone worked.